# Codeigniter: session destroy works well on one server but not in another server with same code and .htaccess file code

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, session, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-2

Hi guys i am trying to run my first web product live from last two days but i am stuck with (session or .htaccess or cookie problem).

Main problem i am facing is 
I have the same code in two different servers both are running on php 5.4 version. and i have kept same .htaccess file in both the server.

**What i tried till:**

first i thought it's a problem with htaccess and then changed htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
Options -Indexes
```

Then i thought it may be problem with cookie or session of codeigniter i read many blogs and answers and changed some times the session variable gets destroy and some time not. and on some controllers the session variables are set and in some controllers they are not set.. Then last i uploaded to another server and there its working perfectly.

email and password to login for both sites
email: demoadmin@gmail.com
password: demoadmin123

The question may be not proper to ask on Stack overflow but i couldn't able to get other places to get a solution. it will be lot helpful if some solutions worked.
If any body suggest good forums to discuss the problem please comment it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: And u load session library in both project properly

Comment: do you have check your custum uri? i have had some problem and my problem was the uri on the config/config

Comment: i am loading session in autoload.php. yeah properly

Comment: i changed request_uri in config file thats also not working.

Comment: i have deleted pre generated cgi-bin folder(empty) hope that will not be a problem

Comment: try set $config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH.'sessions'; path in config.php in config

Comment: finally i changed the server and everything is working fine. i have to ask service provider and i also need to know how to stay safe from bugs like this in next time